# Linear FIlter in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I'm trying to implement a linear filter that makes the difference between the mean of the 3 pixels above the current pixel. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io,color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Image loading
img = io.imread('lena_256.jpg')
img = color.rgb2gray(img)*255
plt.figure(),plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')

img_f1 = img.copy()
size = img.shape


 kernel = np.vstack((np.ones(3),np.zeros(3),-np.ones(3)))
 kernel/=3
for i in range(size[0]-2):
    for j in range(size[1]-2):
        # define the neighborhood - the current pixel will be at line=i+1 and column=j+1
        V = img[i:i+3, j:j+3]
        # multiply each pixel in the neighborhood with the weight in the kernel
        V = V * kernel
        # make the sum of the results and put it in the current pixel
        img_f1[i+1,j+1] = np.sum(V)

# Visualize the result
plt.figure(),plt.imshow(img_f1,cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255 )
```

Comment: Your code is working nicely, it's just such a small change. Try zooming into both images for comparison (and make sure that both `imshow()` use `vmin = 0, vmax = 255` !). To see only what has changed, try: `plt.imshow(img_f1/img, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 1 )`

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you trying to obtain with this linear filter. When you say the _3 pixels above_ what do you mean? Above in position (in which image axis?), in intensity? Maybe you can provide an example with a matrix filled with numbers instead of an image, and the expected output of your filter

Comment: @Roberto for every pixel in the image:

- make the mean of the 3 pixels above (3 pixels on the line above) 

- make the mean of the 3 pixels below (3 pixels on the line below)

- make the difference between those two means and put in the current position in the filtered image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have a problem on the definition of your kernel. With the current kernel definition you are just replacing a pixel by the average intensity value in a 3x3 window centered on the pixel. I believe this is the kernel you want:

```py
kernel = np.vstack((np.ones(3),np.zeros(3),-np.ones(3)))
kernel/=3
print(kernel)

[[ 0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-0.33333333 -0.33333333 -0.33333333]]
```

Be aware though that this kernel will always make the subtraction of the mean above to the mean below, which could result in negative pixel intensities. So when you plot your image, setting `vmin = 0` will make the pixels with negative intensity to appear black. At this point it depends on what you want exactly, you can compare this resulting three plots to decide:

```py
# crop negative img intensities to 0
plt.imshow(img_f1, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255) 

# absolute value of image intensities
plt.imshow(abs(img_f1), cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255) 

# let imshow normalize the data on its own
plt.imshow(img_f1, cmap='gray')

# set minimum and maximum intensity values to the extreme values that could be
# generated by the filtering operation
plt.imshow(img_f1, cmap='gray', vmin = -255, vmax = 255)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've edited the code and I've put the final code there, is it ok?

Comment: I am not expert in Stack overflow so I don't know if that is ok. In my opinion, editing the question so that it includes the answer is not very clear: when people go to a question they will expect to actually find a question, not a mix of question + answer together. If you want to propose your own answer you can post an answer to your question @Robinson-ConstantinChera